# How to compare strings and check threshold equality?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to compare strings and I'd like to test if their chars differs at most `a` elements, for example:

```
// for a = 2 comparing all strings with str1
var str1 = 'qwerty'; // should return true
var str2 = 'qwerty'; // should return true
var str3 = 'qw1rty'; // should return true
var str4 = '1wery1'; // should return true
var str5 = 'q1e11y'; // should return false
```

In order to do this, I created a function which works but I'd wondering if I can make it using `regex`. My actual function:

```js
function test(str1, str2, limit) {
  const occ = str1.split('').reduce((acc, char, idx) => str2[idx] == char ? ++acc : acc, 0);
  return str1.length - occ <= limit;
}

// for a = 2 comparing all strings with str1
var str1 = 'qwerty'; // should return true
var str2 = 'qwerty'; // should return true
var str3 = 'qwert1'; // should return true
var str4 = 'qwer11'; // should return true
var str5 = 'qwe111'; // should return false

console.log(test(str1, str1, 2)) // true
console.log(test(str1, str2, 2)) // true
console.log(test(str1, str3, 2)) // true
console.log(test(str1, str4, 2)) // true
console.log(test(str1, str5, 2)) // false
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `regex`?

Comment: It is (easily) possible with better regex engines than the `JS` one - does it have to be `JavaScript` ?

Comment: I'm actually processing this server-side using `node`, so `javascript` is a requirement

Comment: Side note: The [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a similar (but more advanced) algorithm.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyVzvp?editors=0110

Comment: @guijob: What a pity, see https://paste.ofcode.org/pmvuNLhkPtgXW9PdQiDnRS for a `Python` examples in less than 10 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to match current right letter. If there is no match, capture current character. Then count number of captured characters and compare. For word `qwerty` this would be the regex:

```
(?:q|(.))(?:w|(.))(?:e|(.))(?:r|(.))(?:t|(.))(?:y|(.))
```

JS code:

```js
function testDistance(str1, str2, limit) {
    reStr = '(?:' + str1.split('').join('|(.))(?:') + '|(.))';
    return (new RegExp(reStr)).exec(str2).filter(Boolean).length - 1 <= limit;
}

var str1 = 'qwerty'; // should return true
var str2 = 'qwerty'; // should return true
var str3 = 'qwert1'; // should return true
var str4 = 'qwer11'; // should return true
var str5 = 'qwe111'; // should return false

console.log(testDistance(str1, str1, 2)) // true
console.log(testDistance(str1, str2, 2)) // true
console.log(testDistance(str1, str3, 2)) // true
console.log(testDistance(str1, str4, 2)) // true
console.log(testDistance(str1, str5, 2)) // false
```

Comment: it is not working for my inputs, take a look [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQeGLX?editors=1010).

Comment: Why this `1wery1` should return `true`? This string has `3` characters in different positions that don't match original string.

Comment: awesome. you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the following code to create a regexp from a given string. It then counts the matches of the regexp with the other string in order to determine a distance:

```
function test(str1, str2, limit) {
  // First: Create a regexp from the given input string:
  // "qwerty" -> ["q","w","e","r","t","y"]
  //          -> ["(q)?","(w)?","(e)?","(r)?","(t)?","(y)?"] 
  //          -> (q)?(w)?(e)?(r)?(t)?(y)?
  let regexp = new RegExp(str1.split('').map(e => `(${e})?`).join(''));

  let match = str2.match(regexp);
  if(!match) {
    return false;
  }
  // Now calculate the matches, which did not fulfill the question mark regexp brackets.
  let notEmpty = function(e) { return e; };

  return str2.length - (match.filter(notEmpty).length - 1) <= limit;
}
```

Comment: it's not working for my inputs. take a look [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYXLXv?editors=1010).